# Image not saving Julia sets

Tags: java, image

So I've made a program in Java with the intent to generate an image from some given input. I've managed to get the program to compile and parse input without crashing, but it doesn't seem to be saving the output image.

Here's the stuff pertaining to saving the file:

```
public static void saveImage( BufferedImage img, File file ) throws IOException {

    ImageWriter      writer = null;
    java.util.Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

    if( iter.hasNext() ){
        writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
    }

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( file );
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam( java.util.Locale.getDefault() );
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT) ;
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.98f);

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage( img, null, null ), param);

}


 public static void save(String[] args) throws Exception {

BufferedImage colorImage, julia;

if (args.length != 1)
    System.out.println( "usage is: java Julia filename" );
else
{

julia = Julia();

saveImage( julia,  new File( "julia" + args[0] ) );

}
```

and here's my code in it's entirety:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class Julia{


public static void saveImage( BufferedImage img, File file ) throws IOException {

    ImageWriter      writer = null;
    java.util.Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

    if( iter.hasNext() ){
        writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
    }

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( file );
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam( java.util.Locale.getDefault() );
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT) ;
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.98f);

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage( img, null, null ), param);

}

public static BufferedImage Julia(  ) 

{

//z= (Xmin +i(Xmax- Xmin) /size) + (Ymin+ j(Ymax-Ymin)/size);
    BufferedImage outImage;
    float zreal, zimag;
    float cReal, cImag;  
    float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    int height, width, size;
    height = width = size = 512;
    outImage = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );
    //initializing variables 
    cReal = 0;
    cImag = 0;
    xMin = 0;
    xMax = 0;
    yMin = 0;
    yMax = 0;

    //c= creal+cimag
    Complex c;
     c = new Complex (cReal, cImag);



int i, j ,k;
Complex f;

for (i = 0; i<width; i++)
    {
    for(j = 0; j<height; j++)
        {
        for (k= 0; k< 256; k++)
            {
        zreal = (xMin +i*(xMax- xMin) /size);
        zimag = (yMin+ j*(yMax-yMin)/size);
        Complex z = new Complex( zreal, zimag);

            //z = z^2
            //f= z^2 +c

        z = z.multi(z);
        f = z.addd(c);

        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(zreal, 2.0)+Math.pow(zimag, 2.0))>2)
            break;
            }

    int pixel = getHSBColor(k);
    outImage.setRGB(i, j, pixel);
        }

    }

    return( outImage );

}

public static void main(String[] args)

{
    BufferedImage outImage, julia;
    double cReal, cImag;  
    float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Input: cReal cImag xMin xMax yMin yMax fname");
    cReal=scan.nextDouble ();
    cImag=scan.nextDouble ();
    xMin=scan.nextFloat ();
    xMax=scan.nextFloat ();
    yMin=scan.nextFloat ();
    yMax=scan.nextFloat ();
    String fname = scan.next();


    double f;
    int z;
    int c;
    int height, width, size;
    height = width = size = 512;

    outImage = Julia();  // Put 6 junk inside cReal, cImag, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax

    }

//something I tried to save the file that didn't seem to work properly//
/* try {        
File outputfile = new File( "Julia" + args[0] );
ImageIO.write(julia, "jpg", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {

}*/
     public static void save(String[] args) throws Exception {

BufferedImage colorImage, julia;

if (args.length != 1)
    System.out.println( "usage is: java Julia filename" );
else
{

julia = Julia();

saveImage( julia,  new File( "julia" + args[0] ) );

}   
}
// hsb color table
public static int getHSBColor(int idx)
{
    return Color.getHSBColor((float)(idx/255.0), 1.0f, 1.0f).getRGB();
}


}

class Complex 
{
double real;
double imaginary;

Complex(double newReal, double newImaginary)
{

    real = newReal;
    imaginary = newImaginary;
}

public Complex addd(Complex complexToAdd)
{
    double x , y , newreal, newimaginary;

    newreal = complexToAdd.real;
    newimaginary = complexToAdd.imaginary;
    x = real + newreal;
    y = imaginary + newimaginary;
    Complex newComplex = new Complex(x, y);

    return newComplex;
}

public Complex multi(Complex complexToMulti)
{

    double x, y , newreal, newimaginary;


    newreal = complexToMulti.real;
    newimaginary = complexToMulti.imaginary;

    x = real*newreal - imaginary*newimaginary;
    y = real*newimaginary + imaginary*newreal;

    Complex newComplex= new Complex(x, y);

    return newComplex;
}


// extra absolute value method //
/*public Complex abso (Complex complexAbso) {
double x, y, newreal, newimiginary;

real = complexAbso.real;
imaginary= complexAbso.imaginary;
x = real*real;
y = imaginary*imaginary;

Complex newComplex = new int (x, y);

return newComplex;
}*/
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For saving images to disk, following method can be used:

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Image, format, file);
```

format can be "jpg" or "png". Other variations of the method are also available.

This method is very handy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `ImageIO` might be easier to use when you want to write an image to a file, there's not really something wrong with the code that you currently tried to use for writing the image file.

But with all the rest!

Obviously you are doing quite a lot of trial and error. And one can quickly see from the code that you do not really know what you are doing there. You are not really computing anything, because the values that you enter in your `main` method are not really used in the `Julia` method, and the iteration that is done in the `Julia` method is flawed.

So some general hints:

- Follow the naming conventions
- Make clear to yourself *where* you will use *which* variable
- Keep the scope of variables as small as possible. That means: Declare the variable directly before you want to use it
- As long as you are still experimenting, don't use the `Scanner`. Just define some "default" values for the variables, so that you don't have to enter them again and again each time that you start the program!
- Use a smaller image size. You don't have to wait until a large, 515x512 image is computed to see whether it works or not. A 50x50 image is sufficient for that.

Slightly cleaned up:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Julia
{
    public static BufferedImage julia() 
    {
        int width = 200;
        int height = 100;
        BufferedImage outImage = 
            new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );

        Complex c = new Complex (cReal, cImag);

        for (int i = 0; i<width; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<height; j++)
            {
                double zreal = (xMin +i*(xMax- xMin) / width);
                double zimag = (yMin+ j*(yMax-yMin)/ height);
                Complex z = new Complex( zreal, zimag);

                int k=0;
                for (k= 0; k< 256; k++)
                {
                    z = z.multi(z);
                    z = z.add(c);
//                    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(z.real, 2.0)+
//                        Math.pow(z.imaginary, 2.0))>2)
//                        break;

                    // MUCH faster:
                    if (z.real*z.real+z.imaginary*z.imaginary>4)
                        break;

                }
                int pixel = getHSBColor(k);
                outImage.setRGB(i, j, pixel);
            }
        }
        return outImage;
    }

    static double cReal, cImag;  
    static float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
//        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
//        System.out.println("Input: cReal cImag xMin xMax yMin yMax fname");
//        cReal=scan.nextDouble ();
//        cImag=scan.nextDouble ();
//        xMin=scan.nextFloat ();
//        xMax=scan.nextFloat ();
//        yMin=scan.nextFloat ();
//        yMax=scan.nextFloat ();
//        String fname = scan.next();

        xMin = -2;
        yMin = -1;
        xMax = 2;
        yMax = 1;
        cReal = -0.742;
        cImag = 0.1;

        BufferedImage image = julia();

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("Julia01.jpg"));
        showImage(image);
    }

    public static int getHSBColor(int idx)
    {
        return Color.getHSBColor((float)(idx/255.0), 1.0f, 1.0f).getRGB();
    }

    private static void showImage(final BufferedImage image)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}

class Complex 
{
    double real;
    double imaginary;

    Complex(double newReal, double newImaginary)
    {

        real = newReal;
        imaginary = newImaginary;
    }

    public Complex add(Complex complexToAdd)
    {
        double newreal = complexToAdd.real;
        double newimaginary = complexToAdd.imaginary;
        double x = real + newreal;
        double y = imaginary + newimaginary;
        Complex newComplex = new Complex(x, y);
        return newComplex;
    }

    public Complex multi(Complex complexToMulti)
    {
        double newreal = complexToMulti.real;
        double newimaginary = complexToMulti.imaginary;
        double x = real*newreal - imaginary*newimaginary;
        double y = real*newimaginary + imaginary*newreal;
        Complex newComplex= new Complex(x, y);
        return newComplex;
    }
}
```